# Interactive report: New Computation based on old Computation

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, interactive, oracle-apex-5

Currently, I am using interactive report of Apex 5.0 to show data of my view. My view has column A1, A2

Now, I define new Computation B1 = A1 * 2, B2 = A2 * 2.

After that, how can I use B1, B2 to define new Computation C1=B1*B2 ??

Comment: IR computations are really only intended for end-users to add computed columns without having to engage a developer. Once they start wanting more and more complex computations, they really need to get the developer to add computations into the underlying query for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might have to use

C1=(A1 * 2)*(A2 * 2)

Comment: But if I have a lot of columns, each column is depended on previous column ==> the expression will be hard to view and maintain

Comment: what's wrong with defining a database view then basing the IR on that, with many calculations already configured?

Answer (score 0):

you may use with-clause it may solve your needs partially

check the document http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm

```
with cte as (
    select t.value*2 as b1
)
select
    cte.b1,
    (cte.b1*2) as c1
from cte
```